# In Git, how do I remove files in a folder when they have been removed from the source branch without touching other folders?

Tags: git, merge

I use the following command to checkout a folder from one branch to another:

```
git checkout master foldername
```

It gets the updates of the folder from master to current branches, but it doesn't remove the files in current branch when they've been removed from master. 
I don't want to merge the whole branch. Is there a way to remove all files in a folder in the current branch when they've been removed from master other than manually doing it one by one?

Background:

Recently we migrated over a hundred projects from a CVS repository to a GIT repository. 
We've made four branches in git - master(dev), qa, pt, prod - to indicate the code for different environment. 
In order to move code of one project from one environment to another without merging the others, we switch to the target environment and then checkout from source environment with folder name with the following code:

```
git checkout qa
git checkout master foldername
```

It checks out the updated files fine. But we find that it won't remove files in the target branch when they have been removed from the source branch. We can't make it just merge the whole branch since there might be projects deployed to dev but not ready for QA. 
I guess it is probably not a good way to put some many projects in one repository but as there are so many projects and many of them depends on each other, it is terrifying to separate them.

Comment: I find that I can find all the deleted files using the following command:

    git diff --name-status --diff-filter=D qa..master foldername

And then I can delete them one by one using git rm. But is there a more automatic way? It would be painful if there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files using the foollowing command

```
  rm <path-to-file>
```

Then when just before commiting you need to do the following

```
  git rm <path-to-file>
```

Then, git add and then commit .

Push these changes to remote so as to reflect the changes you made in local .

Comment: That would work. The problem is, if there are a lot of them, I don't want to delete them one by one. Is there a way to find all files and remove them?

Comment: git rm <path-to-file> , a shortcut which i use generally is i give the root folder address of the common files .

Answer (score 0):

For index/worktree plumbing, start with [`git read-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html). Look at [`git checkout-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout-index.html) for specialized worktree ops (and [`git update-index`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) for specialized index ops).  You're going to want some variation on

```
git read-tree -um --prefix=foldername master:foldername
```

depending on what you mean by "update" -- this variant is wholesale replacement, but you can get `read-tree` to propagate or combine changes relative to a baseline by giving it more trees to look at.